# python web2py pysimplesoap client envelope data

Tags: python, rest, post, soap, web2py

I am using web2py pysimplesoap and I try to get data from server. After I call the method I get a response but there are no data in the xml.
Any suggestions?

Here is my code

```
url = "https://www.xxx.ss/demo/aaa/aaa"
#


xml = ("""<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cet="http://xxxx.yy">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <cet:GetEmployedElement>
             <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
             <cet:GetEmployed>
                <cet:OrganizationCode></cet:OrganizationCode>
                <cet:LastName></cet:LastName>
                <cet:FirstName></cet:FirstName>
                <cet:AktCard></cet:AktCard>
                <cet:JobAgreementType></cet:JobAgreementType>
                <cet:Mferac></cet:Mferac>
             </cet:GetEmployed>
          </cet:GetEmployedElement>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
    """)

from gluon.contrib.pysimplesoap.client import SoapClient, SoapFault
client = SoapClient(wsdl="https://www.xxxx.yy/demo/aaa/aaa?wsdl", location="https://www.xxxx.yy", cacert=None, trace=True)
# call SOAP method
#print server.methods['getEmployed']
#print client
print client.getEmployed()
```

and my result is

```
 POST http://192.168.66.53:8380/demo/KadrisData/KadrisData
 SOAPAction: "http://cetrtapot.si/getEmployed"
 Content-length: 269
 Content-type: text/xml; charset="UTF-8"

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope 
 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>

</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And after a while I get a timeout with

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

Answer (score 0):

With simple soap first I needed to set an url where to get the xml since it was calling some internal URL

```
client.services['xxx']['ports']['xxx']['location'] = 'https://www.xxx.yyy/demo/gg/gg'
```

but since i had some xml parsing and other issues I decided to use zeep library, but I also had to do some corrections. I do not know if there is a bug but the call to retrieve data was done wrong so I needed to correct some stuff (See comments in code)

```
client = Client(url ,strict=False)
#In case some parameters expected from envelope were missing I got an error, so I needed to set strict = False
x = client.service.getEmployed
x._proxy._binding_options['address'] = 'https://www.xxxx.yyyy/demo/gggg/gggta'
#a new binding option neede to be set otherwise some internal 192.168.xx.yy was called and that is why I always got an timeout error
```

Hope this helps somebody